# after selecting date how to remove X mark(clear button) in html 5 [input type="date"]

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I know this may seems duplicate question but I still not get clear idea about the clear button in `firefox` and up/down arrows in `chrome`. It occupies more space in my table. I want to remove those functions. I really don't know is there any function in `javascript` or in `CSS`
I tried this:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

but, still getting the same X mark.

[image]

Comment: You can check this one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Chrome you can use

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,    
input[type="date"]::-webkit-clear-button { display: none; }
```

Firefox, on the other hand, doesn't have support for this.

You'd probably be better off using a 3rd party jQuery plugin.

Comment: I found [this](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/) but you can always check the shadow DOM to find out exactly what elements exist.

Comment: MDN is also a good source for pseudo elements (scroll down, in left menu): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements